# Move files from external HDD to new internal HDD while keeping external HDD as backup (rsync)

Tags: backup, rsync

I currently have all my Movies and TV Series (around 2.5TB of data) stored in external HDDs. Recently I bought a new internal HDD for my home server and I wanted to copy all my files there. Up to this point no problem, I used rsync to copy all the files into the new internal HDD. Since I still have the external HDDs with the media content still there, I'd like to use them as backup, i.e. periodically running rsync from my new internal HDD (where I will be upgrading the content) to my external HDDs. However, if I do that, rsync will again copy all the content back as it thinks it was modified, even though it wasn't (I checked it by dry-running rsync). I would like to avoid doing that if possible, since this would be a waste of time and resources. Do you happen to know a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Use the `--ignore-existing` option. See `man rsync` for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately also --ignore-existing doesn't work, it still wants to copy all the files back. I have no idea why.

Comment: Also look at the --modify-window option to relax the precision by which time stamps are compared (sure you kept the time stamps while copying to the new SSD in the first place?). If the latter is the case, try the --size-only option. Yep, as @mikewhatever indicated, see `man rsync`.

Comment: Are both not ext4, or is external NTFS?

Comment: External HDDs are NTFS